# I need to list all the advisors for 3000 level courses and order my results in ascending order by college and major

Tags: sql, oracle

```
    SELECT program.prg_field AS "College"
         , program.prg_name AS "Major"
         , professor.pr_id AS "Professor ID"
         , professor.pr_name AS "Advisor"
      FROM professor
INNER JOIN program ON program.prg_field = professor.pr_college
     WHERE professor.pr_id LIKE '%3%'
  ORDER BY "College"
         , "Major"
         ;
```

My issue is, the pr_id column I'm trying to order by is like this (ex: ACCT3332)
and I have to pick out the first NUMBER and filter out by that to where only courses with numbers that begin with 3 are shown.

Comment: Does the `pr_id` have a specific format (i.e. 4 alphabetical characters then 4 digits) or can it vary?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `REGEXP_LIKE` rather than `LIKE`

```
    SELECT program.prg_field AS "College"
         , program.prg_name AS "Major"
         , professor.pr_id AS "Professor ID"
         , professor.pr_name AS "Advisor"
      FROM professor
INNER JOIN program ON program.prg_field = professor.pr_college
     WHERE REGEXP_LIKE( professor.pr_id, '^\D+3' )
  ORDER BY "College"
         , "Major"
         ;
```

If `pr_id` has the format 4 alphabetical characters then 4 digits then you could also do:

```
     WHERE SUBSTR( professor.pr_id, 5, 1 ) = '3' )
```

or (as suggested by Gordon Linoff)

```
     WHERE professor.pr_id LIKE '____3%'
```

Comment: If it is always the fourth character, you can also use `like '____3%'`.

Comment: @Deniz If this, or another answer, has solved your issue then you can accept the answer (using the check mark below the voting buttons next to the answer) to indicate that the question is closed. If it has not answered your question then you can post a comment detailing the outstanding issues.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the letters from the `pr_id` column value first. You have the following options:

- The `REPLACE` function if there is a small set of possible prefixes to code designations
- The `TRANSLATE` function if you know about the nature of characters used in the prefix of the ocde designation
- `REGEXP_REPLACE` if you know nothing but that there is a number.

Modified query:

```
    SELECT program.prg_field AS "College"
         , program.prg_name AS "Major"
         , professor.pr_id AS "Professor ID"
         , professor.pr_name AS "Advisor"
      FROM professor
INNER JOIN program ON program.prg_field = professor.pr_college
     WHERE TRANSLATE(UPPER(professor.pr_id), '1ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', '1') LIKE '3%'
  ORDER BY "College"
         , "Major"
         ;
```

... or ...

```
     WHERE REPLACE(...REPLACE(professor.pr_id, 'ACCT'), ...) LIKE '3%'
```

... or ...

```
     WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(professor.pr_id, '^[^0-9]*3')
```